# what is the recommend cassandra gui client for cassandra-1.1.2

Tags: cassandra

I'm looking for some gui client for cassandra (like sqlDeveloper) to invoke some basic methods, and run cql queries

Comment: A JDBC driver for Cassandra exists. In principle you can use it with SQuirreL SQL to run CQL queries. I'm a big fan of SQuirreL... but I have never tried it with Cassandra.

Comment: https://javaresolutions.blogspot.com/2018/04/opensource-db-ui-tool-for-cassandra-db.html I followed this, and successfully connected to cassandra running on dockder

Answer (score 66):

[Dbeaver](http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/) in its free enterprise version (not open source) is good GUI client for Cassandra. No need of installation. Its portable. Also this client supports more than 20 databases.

Community Edition of Dbeaver doesn't have support for Cassandra, but we can use third party drivers for like [Cdata](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/cassandra-jdbc-dbvr.rst) to connect.

Try the following  GUI client also

**Up to date**:

- [Datastax](http://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-opscenter)
- [Netflix Data Explorer](https://github.com/Netflix/nf-data-explorer)
- [RazorSQL](http://razorsql.com/features/cassandra_database_client_gui.html)
- [Dbschema](https://www.dbschema.com/cassandra-designer-tool.html)
- [Aquafold](http://www.aquafold.com/dbspecific/apache_cassandra_client)
- [squirrel-sql](https://sourceforge.net/projects/squirrel-sql/)
- [Cassandra-UI-Editor](https://github.com/parag3gwl/Cassandra-UI-Editor)
- [cassandra-web](https://github.com/avalanche123/cassandra-web)

**Paid tools**

- [NoSQL Manager for Cassandra](https://www.mongodbmanager.com/cassandra/#)
- [TablePlus](https://tableplus.com)
- [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/)

**Development stopped**

- http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-gui/
- http://blog.shelan.org/2012/06/cassandra-gui-20-making-things-little.html
- https://github.com/sebgiroux/Cassandra-Cluster-Admin
- https://github.com/libjack/cassandra-gui
- https://github.com/tomekkup/helenos#readme
- https://github.com/Kindrat/cassandra-client

Comment: At first time, When we launch the dbeaver then it shows that 'Select new connection type' option to choose, what should i choose for cassandra?

Comment: It seems that you need to download the free *Enterprise Edition* of *dbeaver* to open cassandra databases.

Comment: Export using Dbeaver doesn't work on Ubuntu. It always throws NullPointerException :( 

Has any body faced the same ?

Comment: I'm also getting NullPointerException except on Windows and with trying to execute my own queries. I've been looking for GUI client but will likely go with a commercial product specifically for Cassandra. There are a couple inexpensive ones I've found (CassViewer and another one that was only $35 -- I forgot the name).

Comment: It doesn't support on free edition. There is no choice for Cassandra on Connection Type

Comment: Yup, we can't use dbeaver enterprise free version to connect to Cassandra, it is not listed in the list of database supported in new Connection Type.

Comment: @PrasadRevanaki Try old version

Comment: I confirm, tried free enterprise edition and it contains Cassandra CQL option(4.05 EE version vs 4.10 of CE). Link to it you may find on community edition page and it's said: _EE version is also free but it is not open-source._

Comment: DBeaver Enterprise version till 3.x.x supports Cassandra connection. You would need to configure the Driver for connection. Search for DBeaver Cassandra connection and should find few blogs From 4.x.x version, DBeaver Enterprise is limited to few days of free usage.

Comment: Go go  https://www.dbschema.com/cassandra-jdbc-driver.html 
The driver is provided at https://www.dbschema.com/jdbc-drivers/CassandraJdbcDriver.zip

Comment: @twindai thanks for the dbschema.com driver link, it was useful. I documented the exact steps how to set it up with SQuirreL SQL: https://gist.github.com/attila123/d52d521a0f25fc912ec86a77c7c0a30d

Comment: @Attila123 Thank you, this was very helpful! One issue I had was I had to select all the files in the folder I extracted the driver files to, not just the folder they were in. Otherwise, this was perfect!

Answer (score 8):

Check out [Helenos](https://github.com/tomekkup/helenos#readme) - it's a simple web based tool. Cql is now supported (from Version 1.3).

Comment: A tool to "run cql queries" which does not support cql is of limited help.

Comment: Cql support has been added to wish list

Comment: Helenos doesn't work for tables with compound primary keys. There's a request to support this here https://github.com/tomekkup/helenos/issues/16